# How to save cart information securely using Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am developing an eCommerce website using angular 7. Currently I am saving the cart information in localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(this.items));
```

But i found that saved cart information can be alter/delete from browser console.so i am looking for a more secure option which need to be invisible from the user.

Looking for any suggestion or useful link that can be referred and implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sensible and secure information should be saved and retrieved from the backend.

Comment: Yes, from the browser console, localstorage could be modified as well delete.
The best way is to store it for server-side.
Or on the front side, store it in encrypted form but that can be modified

Comment: Everything in the frontend can be modified and deleted. You can use cookies and db functions to store those data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the data in `localStorage` is not an option as soon as more than one user interacts with. Your eCommerce website needs a server and a data storage tier, both decoupled from the client. I recommend the use of [Apache's CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/), which is a NoSQL database using a `JSON` based document format. CouchDB bundles the server and data storage functionality in a single product, providing a REST-like interface for document insertion, updates, retrieval and deletion. [Apache CouchDB Nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) is the official Node.js library for use with CouchDB.

Many other factors speach for CouchDB:

- It is open source.
- It is available for Linux, macOS and Windows.
- It can be installed on your local computer (for development), on your own servers, or in the cloud.
- It is shipped with [Fauxton](https://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/index.html) web interface that lets you create, update, delete, view and query documents on the fly.
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an eCommerce website, it is always best practice to store the cart information in the DB. This provides with the advantage of creating a user requirement and purchase partern which can help build new shopping recommendations for the user.

Also consider the scenario where the user uses mobile app to add items to cart and checkouts using webapp. In this scenario also you tend to lose data.

Also, consider the scenario where the user wants to log off and do the purchase later. In this case, using localStorage is not recommended. **It would be best practice to use DB for the same.**